# iPhone UITableViewCell performance adding multiple Views vs one View with drawRect

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage, uilabel, drawrect

I am creating some `UITableViewCells` with several custom items inside, my question is what route to go:

1) Add all I need as separate views to contentView, using `UILabels` for text and `UIImageViews` for images (currently using this)

or

2) Add a single subclassed View to contentView, and all my text as `NSString` then my Images and `UIImages` and draw everything at drawRect

What would perform better, and in what scenarios would one be the better choice over the other?, as I see it unless you are actually drawing lines or something in the contentView, simply going with option 1 would be easier, and according to this [Cocoa with love custom cells](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) it is more efficient although it is a bit old, so I don't know if this has changed.

So what is better for performance and in which situation would you definitely use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the first method of using separate UILabel's and UIImageView's. Test on actual devices and optimize if you see performance problems.

Depending on the content I've had option 1 be faster than drawing everything in one view. Especially when that view had to draw images. UIImageView's are heavily optimized by apple.

A good way to get metrics on performance is the Core Animation instrument.

Answer (score 1):

I think drawing the text yourself would be marginally more efficient. However, as long as you keep the backgrounds of all your labels opaque, I doubt the difference would be enough to matter, so go with whatever is easiest to program, and avoid premature optimisation.

(The opaque backgrounds thing is quite important — labels with transparent backgrounds are a big cause of inefficiency in table views. Even so, unless you have hundreds it probably won't be much of a problem.)